# How to conditionally partition observations into groups?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following input:

```
C1  C2
1   1
1   1
1   2
1   3
1   4
2   1
.   .
```

C1 and C2 are groups, where C2 is a nested group within C1. Now I'd like to build subgroups on C1 having a minimum size of 2. While the groups in C2 should not be split, I'd like to have as many groups as possible. Manually, I would first have a look at the group C1 and join subgroups 2, 3 and 4 together to (G=1) and take the subgroup 1 (C2=1) as a group (G=2). The expected output would be (where G are the groups I try to create)

```
C1  C2  G
1   1   1
1   1   1
1   2   2
1   3   2
1   4   2
2   1   3
.   .   .
```

I hope it's clear what I mean. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Do not understand. You can explain better

Comment: What do you mean by "the values in C2 should not be split"? If you have C2 = 1 for a couple of times they need to be in one group?

Comment: Sorry for the messy explanation. I tried to make it more clear - I hope it helps.

Comment: I am not completely clear on the rules either but maybe this greedy approach does it: `ff <- function(x) { 
   y <- replace(0 * x, 1, 1);
   size <- 0;
   for(i in seq_along(x)) {
    size <- size + 1;
    if (x[i] && size > 2) { y[i] <- 1; size <- 1 };
   };
   y
};
G0 <- ave(DF$C1, DF$C1, DF$C2, FUN = function(x) replace(0*x, 1, 1));
G <- cumsum(ave(G0, DF$C1, FUN = ff));
cbind(DF, G)`

Comment: @ Gregor. Fixed. Sorry about that. I fixed it for the duplicate and thought the questions were merged.

Comment: It's hard to know what to do here from a site organization perspective. It seems like you asked a (low quality) question, got an answer, it was put on hold, and then you edited it into what seems like a different question, then you copied the edits into a new question which got closed as a duplicate of this one. *At this point*, it looks like a good question, but you've edited it so that Jaap's answer is no longer relevant. It's discouraged to make heavy edits after getting an answer as it invalidates the work that was done.

Comment: My suggestion is that you should (1) copy the current version to a new question and (2) roll back the drastic edits so that the new question is not a duplicate and Jaap's answer still seems relevant. We can leave this one closed, and you can get help at the new question without having to go through the hassle of re-opening, figuring out what to do with Jaap's answer, etc.

Comment: @ Gregor I agree - that was never my intention. I appreciate any effort someone put into answering my question. I am very sorry. How can I roll it back?

Comment: I rolled it back as far as I could tell

Comment: I've rolled it back to the last point where the question and my answer match. @Gregor: In my opinion the other question is now eligible for reopening. What do you think?

Answer (score 2):

Using:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mydf)[, G := {r <- rep(1:floor(.N/2), each = 2); if(length(r) != .N) c(r, tail(r,1)) else r}
            , by = C1
            ][, G := rleid(G)][]
```

you get:

> ```
>     C1 C2 G
>  1:  1  1 1
>  2:  1  1 1
>  3:  1  2 2
>  4:  1  3 2
>  5:  1  4 2
>  6:  2  1 3
>  7:  2  1 3
>  8:  2  2 4
>  9:  2  3 4
> 10:  2  4 4
> 11:  3  1 5
> 12:  3  2 5
> 13:  3  3 6
> 14:  3  4 6
> 15:  3  5 6
> ```

---

Used data:

```
mydf <- structure(list(C1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), 
                       C2 = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L)), 
                  .Names = c("C1", "C2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -15L))
```

Comment: Hm, output line 11 should be in group 3, but is in group 5...

Comment: @donjoe That can't be concluded from the description of OP imo. For the time being I've removed that row from the example until it's clear what OP wants do with such edge cases.

Comment: This code does not use C2.